# The orientation of an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: differential-forms, smooth-manifolds

Assume $M$ is an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$ with codimension 1, by a specific coordinate of $\mathbb R^n$ $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ in an area $U$, the $M\cap U$ has coordinate $\{x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}\}$. Under this coordinate,the orientation of $\mathbb R^n$ can be determined by the standard volume form $dx_1\wedge dx_2\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n$, so the standard volume form of $dx_1\wedge dx_2\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{n-1}$, thus the submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$ is orientable? Am I right?

Comment: I don't think that suffices. You've shown that $M\cap U$ is orientable, but you need to show the form you produced extends to a nowhere vanishing form on all of $M$ in order to conclude that $M$ is orientable.

Comment: In fact, depending on the definition of embedded submanifold, your claim might be false. Consider embedding the Mobius band in $\mathbb R^3$, for example.

Comment: @ Patrick, Thanks, I think you are right, actually, I arise this question from proving the preimage of regular value of a smooth function from $R^n$ to R is orientable. Could you give me some ideas about this question?

Comment: See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384700/show-that-the-zero-set-of-f-is-an-orientable-submanifold-of-bbb-rn1

Comment: @Patrick, I guess the result also holds for the case that the function is on a manifold M, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32760/discussion-between-6666-and-patrick).

Comment: I don't know, sorry.