# Nowhere vanishing form on zero set of $f$ - understanding the solution

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying to understand the solution to constructing a $C^\infty$ nowhere vanishing form on a regular level set of $f(x^1,\dots,x^{n+1})$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

There is a solution here

[Show that the zero set of $f$ is an orientable submanifold of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384700/show-that-the-zero-set-of-f-is-an-orientable-submanifold-of-bbb-rn1)

where we have $$\omega=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{i-1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}dx_1\wedge\cdots \wedge dx_{i-1}\wedge dx_{i+1}\wedge\cdots \wedge dx_{n+1}$$

but I don't understand the reasoning of

> Since $0$ is a regular value of $f$,
> $$df\wedge \omega= \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right)^2dx_1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_{n+1}$$
> is nowhere vanishing on $f^{-1}(0)$. It implies that the restriction of $\omega$ on $f^{-1}(0)$ is nowhere vanishing, so it induces an orientation of $f^{-1}(0)$.

How does this show $\omega$ is no where vanishing on $f^{-1}(0)$?

Also can someone explain to me how this gives the 'normal vector' to the surface (see comments in link).

Furthermore, there is the solution I think my textbook implies and I'm not sure if it's related in any way to this solution. The problem is outlined here [image: Tu Introduction to Manifolds]

and I think the solution implied here is something like recognizing that the $$\frac{dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \widehat{dx^i} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{n+1}}{f_{x^i}}$$

are all equal, and hence, one of them will always be defined since one of the $f_{x^i}$ will always be nonzero since 0 is a regular value.

Is this the correct generalization and is it related to the StackExchange solution in any way?

Comment: Use the regularity. Assume $\omega$ vanishes somewhere. Derive a contradiction. Can elaborate if you want.

Comment: Suppose there is a point $p \in f^{-1}(0)$ where $\omega_p \equiv 0$. Then $(df \wedge \omega)_p = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} (f_{x^i})^2 dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{n+1} = 0$. But this is only true if $\partial f/ \partial x^i = 0$ for all $x^i$, contradicting regularity of $f$. Is this right?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it.